# supervising syslog-ng doesnot run in the background

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

Below is my syslog-ng unit script. I could see there is no process with supervising syslog-ng running. Whenever syslog-ng is failed, I had to restart manually . Can anyone please let me now if we can automate script to run the syslog-ng if it is failing/stopped.

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service
 [Service]
 Type=notify
 Sockets=syslog.socket
 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid --fd-limit=90000
 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
 StandardOutput=null
 Restart=on-failure

ps aux |grep syslog-ng
root     12548  110  1.1 8715368 6856976 ?     xxx  Mar21 2719:38 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid --fd-limit=90000
```

Answer (score 0):

The supervisor process of syslog-ng is used only on init.d systems.

With systemd, the same functionality can be achieved by configuring the `Restart`-related options of the service (`sudo systemctl edit syslog-ng`):

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=

Comment: I have added restart= on-Failure, syslog-ng is restarting multiple times, After 3 restarts it is entering into failure status and had to restart manually.

Comment: StartLimitIntervalSec and StartLimitBurst should be set accordingly: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval